# jQuery prevent change for select

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, select

I want to prevent a select box from being changed if a certain condition applies.  Doing this doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#my_select').bind('change', function(ev) {
  if(my_condition)
  {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

I'm guessing this is because by this point the selected option has already changed.

What are other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qk2Pc/

```
var my_condition = true;
var lastSel = $("#my_select option:selected");

$("#my_select").change(function(){
  if(my_condition)
  {
    lastSel.prop("selected", true);
  }
});

$("#my_select").click(function(){
    lastSel = $("#my_select option:selected");
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Instead of using the lastSel closure I simply assigned a "last_selected" class to the last selected option and later looked for that option and reassigned it.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution is not working in JQuery 3.1.1 and above. Any other way?

Answer (score 32):

In the event someone needs a generic version of mattsven's answer (as I did), here it is:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    $(this).data('lastSelected', $(this).find('option:selected'));
});

$('select').change(function() {
    if(my_condition) {
        $(this).data('lastSelected').attr('selected', true);
    }
});

$('select').click(function() {
    $(this).data('lastSelected', $(this).find('option:selected'));
});
```

Comment: This is great, but you no need the first each. Click event have the same before change every time.

Comment: Great generic answer! One point - what if the user tabs and uses a keyboard to select? So better use focus instead of click in the third block. And I agree with David.

Comment: I edited it to change click to focus to make it keyboard friendly (see: http://jsfiddle.net/VTUnK ) , but luckily the edit was rejected as I just found out a bug... The focus triggers even if we open a dialog and close it so if we want to restore the selection after that, it won't work. So if we want to make it keyboard friendly, we need to use the above code, and also map it to keydown as well.

Comment: @msanjay nice job; I added a couple of enhancements as well: http://jsfiddle.net/VTUnK/7/ Now you can can cancel other attached events to that select;mattsven dwallace - this answer should be updated with msanjay's (or my) updates

Comment: Good job, but I have to unselect the new value with: `$(this).find('option:selected').attr('selected', false);` before `$(this).data('lastSelected').attr('selected', true);`

Comment: @nickel715 try using `prop` instead of `attr`

Answer (score 10):

If you simply want to prevent interaction with the select altogether when my_condition is true, you could always just capture the mousedown event and do your event prevent there:

```
var my_condition = true;

$("#my_select").mousedown(function(e){
  if(my_condition)
  {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("Because my_condition is true, you cannot make this change.");
  }
});
```

This will prevent any change event from ever occurring while my_condition is true.

Comment: Even if the user presses the up or down key to change the selection when the input has focus?

Comment: You might be able to use tabindex=-1
Or you could add jQuery that detects focus and triggers it on the next element

Answer (score 2):

Another option to consider is disabling it when you do not want it to be able to be changed and enabling it:

```
//When select should be disabled:
{
    $('#my_select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

//When select should not be disabled
{
    $('#my_select').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

**Update since your comment (if I understand the functionality you want):**

```
$("#dropdown").change(function()
{
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to change your selection?")
    {
        if(answer)
        {
            //Update dropdown (Perform update logic)
        }
        else
        {
            //Allow Change (Do nothing - allow change)
        } 
    }            
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CHTfp/2/)

Comment: I need them to be able to change the select at all times. When they change the select it a dynamic sortable list of items of they've selected is no longer valid.  I need to warn them that that is the case before I clear that list.  If they decide not to have that list clear then I need to make sure the select change doesn't happen.

Comment: So you want the user to be able to change it whenever - however when they change it - prompt them if they want the change to occur - otherwise do nothing? Something similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/CHTfp/2/

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked well for me. The easy solution in my case was:

```
$("#selectToNotAllow").focus(function(e) {
    $("#someOtherTextfield").focus();
});
```

This accomplishes clicking or tabbing to the select drop down and simply moves the focus to a different field (a nearby text input that was set to readonly) when attempting to focus on the select. May sound like silly trickery, but very effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without jquery...

```
<select onchange="event.target.selectedIndex = 0">
...
</select>
```

or you can do a function to check your condition

```
<select onchange="check(event)">
...
</select>

<script>
function check(e){
    if (my_condition){
        event.target.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for "javascript prevent select change" on Google and this question comes at first result. At the end my solution was:

```
const $select = document.querySelector("#your_select_id");
let lastSelectedIndex = $select.selectedIndex;
// We save the last selected index on click
$select.addEventListener("click", function () {
    lastSelectedIndex = $select.selectedIndex;
});

// And then, in the change, we select it if the user does not confirm
$select.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    if (!confirm("Some question or action")) {
        $select.selectedIndex = lastSelectedIndex;
        return;
    }
    // Here do whatever you want; the user has clicked "Yes" on the confirm
    // ...
});
```

I hope it helps to someone who is looking for this and does not have jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the ".live" option in jQuery since the behavior will be evaluated in real-time based on the condition you've set.

```
$('#my_select').live('change', function(ev) {
  if(my_condition)
  {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: live vs bind is not the answer.  The live function makes it so that the element your selecting doesn't necessarily have to exist when you're assigning the handler.  Behind-the-scenes, I believe, it actually sets a listener on the document and then dynamically applies the handler to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Implement custom readonly like eventHandler

```
<select id='country' data-changeable=false>
  <option selected value="INDIA">India</option>
  <option value="USA">United States</option>
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
</select>

<script>
    var lastSelected = $("#country option:selected");

    $("#country").on("change", function() {
       if(!$(this).data(changeable)) {
            lastSelected.attr("selected", true);              
       }        
    });

    $("#country").on("click", function() {
       lastSelected = $("#country option:selected");
    });
</script>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/0mvajuay/8/

Comment: its not about browser but jQuery version. looks like jsfiddle uses a higher version by default now. Select "Migrate to 1.2.1" and it still works :)

Answer (score 0):

This was the ONLY thing that worked for me (on Chrome Version 54.0.2840.27):

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  $(this).data('lastSelectedIndex', this.selectedIndex);
});
$('select').click(function() {
  $(this).data('lastSelectedIndex', this.selectedIndex);
});

$('select[class*="select-with-confirm"]').change(function() {  
  if (!confirm("Do you really want to change?")) {
    this.selectedIndex = $(this).data('lastSelectedIndex');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='fruits' class="select-with-confirm">
  <option selected value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
  <option value="melons">Melons</option>
</select>

<select id='people'>
  <option selected value="john">John</option>
  <option value="jack">Jack</option>
  <option value="jane">Jane</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, no need to keep a `lastSelected` if you know the `optionIndex` to select.

```
var optionIndex = ...
$(this)[0].options[optionIndex].selected = true;
```

Comment: This didn't work. No errors, just did the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#my_select').bind('mousedown', function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

if anybody still interested, this solved the problem, using jQuery 3.3.1

```
jQuery('.class').each(function(i,v){

    jQuery(v).data('lastSelected', jQuery(v).find('option:selected').val());
    jQuery(v).on('change', function(){

    if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))
    {
        var self = jQuery(this);
        jQuery(this).find('option').each(function(key, value){
           if(parseInt(jQuery(value).val()) === parseInt(self.data('lastSelected')))
           {
               jQuery(this).prop('selected', 'selected');
           }
        });
    }
    jQuery(v).data('lastSelected', jQuery(v).find('option:selected').val());    
});
```

});

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58661488/edit) to include an explanation of your code, and how it's different or better than the other eleven answers. The original question is almost *nine years old*, and answers without explanation tend to get downvoted or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, here is what eventually did.

I had to track the previous selected value of the select element and store it in the data-* attribute.  Then I had to use the val() method for the select box that JQuery provides.  Also, I had to make sure I was using the value attribute in my options when I populated the select box.

```
<body>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>        <!-- Must use the value attribute on the options in order for this to work. -->
        <option value="Bannana">Bannana</option>
        <option value="Cherry">Cherry</option>
    </select>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready()
    {
        //
        // Register the necessary events.
        $("#sel").on("click", sel_TrackLastChange);
        $("#sel").on("keydown", sel_TrackLastChange);
        $("#sel").on("change", sel_Change);
        
        $("#sel").data("lastSelected", $("#sel").val());
    }
    
    //
    // Track the previously selected value when the user either clicks on or uses the keyboard to change
    // the option in the select box.  Store it in the select box's data-* attribute.
    function sel_TrackLastChange()
    {
        $("#sel").data("lastSelected", $("#sel").val());
    }
    
    //
    // When the option changes on the select box, ask the user if they want to change it.
    function sel_Change()
    {
        if(!confirm("Are you sure?"))
        {
            //
            // If the user does not want to change the selection then use JQuery's .val() method to change
            // the selection back to what it was  previously.
            $("#sel").val($("#sel").data("lastSelected"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

I hope this can help someone else who has the same problem as I did.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGV***)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.post("/home/getvisits")

        .done(function (res) {
         
            for (var item in res) {

                $("#table").append(
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + res[item].pkID + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + res[item].Name + " " + res[item].Family + "</td>"+              
                    "<td>" + res[item].Tshamsi + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + res[item].Pname + " " + res[item].Pfamily + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + res[item].Mobile + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + res[item].VisitType + "</td>" +
                    "<td class='status'  align='center' id=status-" + res[item].pkID + "  onclick='get(this.id)'>" + "<select class='o1'   onchange='getValue(this.value)'>" + "<option>" + res[item].Status + "</option>" +"</select>"+"</td>"

                );

            }

        })

        .fail(function () {
           
        })

        .always(function () {

        })   
})

function getValue(data) {
    var e = document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML;
    var myDiv = e.split("-");
    var chdata = data;
    var spdata = chdata.split("-");
    $.post("/home/setdatastate", { myDiv: myDiv[1], spdata: spdata[0] })

        .done(function (res) {
            if (res == 1) {
                location.reload();
            }

        })

        .fail(function () {


        })

        .always(function () {



        })
}


function get(getdata) {
    var i = getdata;
    document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = i;
    $.post("/home/setstatus")

        .done(function (res) {
            $(".o1").empty();
            for (var item in res) {

                $(".o1").append(

                    "<option>" + res[item].pkID + "-" + res[item].Status + "</option>"

                );

            }


        })

        .fail(function () {



        })

        .always(function () {



        })

}
```

```html
<p id="ch" style="display: none"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="filters">
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ردیف" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="مشخصات پزشک" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ مراجعه" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="مشخصات بیمار" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="شماره همراه بیمار" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="نوع ویزیت" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="وضعیت" disabled></th>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody id="table">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

***6l.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).