# Select change event does not preserve last selected

Tags: jquery, select

have 5 Select controls on a page, each with the same option values and when I select one value in first dropdown, I shouldn't be allowed to select the same value again in the others. I tried something like below.

```
$("#div").find(".selectClass").live("change", function (e) {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var controlId = $(this).attr("id");
    var isPropertyAlreadySelected = false;

    $("#div").find(".selectClass").each(function () {
        var currentSelect = $(this);
        if (controlId != currentSelect.attr("id") && currentSelect.val() == selectedValue) {
            isPropertyAlreadySelected = true;
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT: Removed check on the flag "isPropertyAlreadySelected"; but still I'm able to select other dropdown values.**

Even if I do a "return false" or "e.preventDefault()", the value is still getting selected in the other dropdowns. Please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Uhm, where is `$/jQuery` in your selectors?

Comment: Sorry, missed them in the question; but have 'em in the actual code base.

Comment: Can you disable other options based on the selected values?

Comment: No, I cant disable other options as per architects call

Comment: Try moving `var isPropertyAlreadySelected = false;` before the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running in is, that the value of the select has already changed when your change event fires.

You need to have a list of the currently selected values and reset the changed option here:

```
if (isPropertyAlreadySelected) {
    // Reset here
}
```

Just fill an array with the values that are selected at page load and update this array every time an option gets selected.

I have just tested with the mousedown event. This one fires before the option realy got selected. Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/g3rsF/1/

This will not solve for all cases, as the user can select by keypress also.

Comment: Ya, this would be a work around that I was thinking about; but my first impression was that "return false" and/or "e.preventDefault()" would reset to the previously selected value. Is that not the case?

Comment: Nope, they both don't reset. You will have to reset by yourself

Comment: So, I have been using mousedown event to store the old value and assigning that back to the dropdown on the change event, if the same value was selected in any other dropdown. Thanks for the idea!!

Comment: But keep in mind, that a user can also select the values by using only his/her keyboard. So you would also have to add some handling of keyboard events

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it seems not possible, as the value already changed.

Please see this related question and solution: [jQuery prevent change for select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426387/jquery-prevent-change-for-select)

Here is a minimal reproduce of the issue in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eranmedan/vL5JY/4/)

Comment: Even if I don't check for bool var "isPropertyAlreadySelected" and do a "return false" and/or "e.preventDefault()", it's still selecting the new value instead of preserving the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Save the current selected item on the dropdown and work with this little helper :)

```
<select id="s1" class="selectClass">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="s2" class="selectClass">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>​
```

.

```
$(document).on("change", ".selectClass", function(ev) {
    var cur = $(this),
        text = cur.find("option:selected").text(),
        isAlreadySelected;

    isAlreadySelected = $(".selectClass").not("#" + this.id).filter(function() {
        return $(this).find("option:selected").text() === text;
    });

    if (isAlreadySelected.length) {
        cur.prop("selectedIndex", cur.prop("selIdx") || 0);
    }

    cur.data("selIdx", cur.prop("selectedIndex"));
});​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4pBc3/)