# Add select option and validate it

Tags: jquery, validation, select

I have a difficult problem which I can't solve myself.

I have a dynamic select box with an option selected by default, like so:

```
    <select id="product_configure_variants">
      <option value="8830685" selected="selected">nicotine</option>
      <option value="8831010">6mg nicotine</option>
      <option value="8831011">12mg nicotine</option>
     </select>
```

I have added with Jquery a new option on top of the others, like so:

```
$('#product_configure_variants').prepend('<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="">Choose</option>');
```

Now the html looks like this:

```
    <select id="product_configure_variants">
      <option value="" selected="" disabled="disabled">Choose</option>
      <option value="8830685" selected="selected">nicotine</option>
      <option value="8831010">6mg nicotine</option>
      <option value="8831011">12mg nicotine</option>
     </select>
```

I want to force people to choose one of the 3 options and make the first ("Choose") non-selectable but shown first. 
I think I have to validate the form, but I don't want to use a plugin.

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Try `if(!$('#product_configure_variants').val()){alert('select!!!')}`

Comment: Your id attributes have # in them, you should remove those. <select id="product_configure_variants">

Comment: @Milanzor: It was a typo... it's fixed now!

Comment: I think this will get you on your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426387/jquery-prevent-change-for-select

Comment: Note that the disabled attribute already gives you what you want, all you have to do is remove the selected attribute from the other options: http://jsfiddle.net/P4DHL/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var option = $('<option>').text('- Chose one -');
$('#product_configure_variants').prepend(option).val('- Chose one -');

$('#my-form').submit(function(e){
    if ($('#product_configure_variants').val() == '- Chose one -') {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Warning! You have to select one!');
        $('#product_configure_variants').addClass('req');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9HGUp/

Comment: Ok thx that helped a lot! The only thing that doesn't work right now is that the select box doesn't change to the selected option and keeps "Chose one" as selected... How to fix that inside your code? I tried it with the change function but that doesn't work

Comment: I've interpreted your question as that you have a system (framework/cms) that when you fill in a new item you want the javascript to run and that when editing an item you do not want it to run. Am I correct? If that is the case then I would recommend searching for a class in the DOM which lets you determine if the item is new or not. ie: <body class="create-new">. With that class you have several options. You can wrap the code in a simple logic statement. `if ($('body.create-new').length) { /* .. code here .. */ }` or you could add `body.create` to the beginning of your selectors.