# Prevent html option from changing even after user select

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem, when ever user selects from dropdown I need to check if there are changes that the user made before I allow the user to fully go to the next thing he/she should fill-out.

Is there a way to set the dropdown to it's previous value if there are changes made?

```
<select id="dropdown" >
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why don't you disable the select when those changes are made.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426387/jquery-prevent-change-for-select
answer here http://jsfiddle.net/qk2Pc/

Comment: You might be interested in [this SO post discussing the use of the `disabled` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input). there is one catch (which the answers address) as disabled selections aren't included by default in the form parameters sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var prevVal=$('#dropdown').val();
$('#dropdown').on('click','option',function(){
   if(prevVal==this.value){
      alert('no change');   
   } else{
       prevVal = this.value;
       alert('value changed');       
   }       
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/r5kY4/)

**Updated** use `click event` on `dropdown` like,

```
var prevVal=$('#dropdown').val();
$('#dropdown').on('click',function(){
   if(prevVal==this.value){
       console.log('no change');   
   } else{
       prevVal = this.value;
       console.log('value changed');       
   }       
});
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/r5kY4/1/)

Comment: It's not displaying the message.

Comment: Did you change the options?

Comment: It's not working on me. There are errors on console.

Comment: What errors? Don't forget to include the latest version of jquery in your page.

Comment: I tried it in mozilla and it's working but it's not working on chrome.

Comment: @user3462803 try my updated answer and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/r5kY4/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var previous = $('#dropdown').val();
$('#dropdown').change(function()
{
   if(previous ==this.value)
  {
      //do things   
  } 
  else
  {
      previous = this.value;
      //do things         
  }       
});
```

Try this.