# How to prevent changing of select option after cancelling confirm using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox, confirm

So I have an select option field, and what  I change the option of select field a confirm message will show. My problem is how do I prevent of changing the value of select option field after cancelling the confirmation message.

```
$('.changeScoreFem').on('change', function(){
    if (confirm('Are you sure to change this score?')) {
        //continue to change  the value
    } else {
        //else do not change the selecoption field value
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery prevent change for select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426387/jquery-prevent-change-for-select)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by storing current value of select, then undo it as needed.

Following uses a custom event to store the data and that custom event is also triggered on page load in case you pass selected items from server

```
var $sel = $('.changeScoreFem').on('change', function(){
    if (confirm('Are you sure to change this score?')) {
        // store new value        
        $sel.trigger('update');
    } else {
         // reset
         $sel.val( $sel.data('currVal') );        
    }
}).on('update', function(){
    $(this).data('currVal', $(this).val());
}).trigger('update');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8jbrm2kg/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Simple / elegant solution, works great!

Answer (score 2):

You need to store selected option in variable and if confirm canceled, reselect it.

```js
var selected = $(".changeScoreFem option:selected");
$(".changeScoreFem").on("change", function(e){
    if (confirm("Are you sure to change this score?"))
        selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    else
        selected.prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="changeScoreFem">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```