# Prevent the updation of dropdown select conditionally

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to achieve a change event handler to a dropdown select. In that, I have to conditionally prevent the select update.

**Please find the fiddler sample that I tried**
https://jsfiddle.net/Linoy/rxdtcquw/19/

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option class='no-update'>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>


$('select').change(function(event) {

     if ($(this).find(":selected").hasClass('no-update')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Unfortunalty selector is changing here..');
      }
});
```

After searchingStackOverflowflow, I found a solution here but for me, it is not working above JQuery 1.5.2 versions.

[jQuery prevent change for select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426387/jquery-prevent-change-for-select)

Any other idea or fix to achieve the same?

Comment: you need to hack this, because we cant prevent dropdown changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated few line of code of your code snippet you can find it below:

```js
var lastSelection = $("#my_select option:selected");
$('select').change(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('no-update')) {
    lastSelection.prop("selected", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select">
    <option class='no-update'>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

At first, i have stored the initially selected value to a variable. then i made a change in `if condition`.
so i have changed

```
if ($(this).find(":selected").hasClass('no-update')){}
```

to

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('no-update')){}
```

So **if this condition met true it retain the previous state.**

```
lastSelection.prop("selected", true);
```

Below is another possible solution in which we are not using `.no-update` class instead it uses `confirm box` to update select options

```js
var lastSelection = $("#my_select option:selected");
$('#my_select').change(function() {
  if (confirm('Are You Sure? Do you want to continue?')) {
    lastSelection = $(this).find('option:selected');
  }else{
    lastSelection.prop("selected", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: .i just know if we can save 2 snippet. +1