# :read-only selector not working on select tag?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make select tag read only means it should not be selectable, when i try to add attribute readonly it works fine but it is also applying on select tag which do not have readonly attribute, i think i'm not applying selector properly,

I cannot set it disabled because it won't submit along with form details, this is what i've tried in w3school editor :-

```css
select:-moz-read-only {
  /* For Firefox */
  pointer-events: none;
}

select:read-only {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p> ACCEPTED </p>
<select readonly>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<br>
<p> UNACCEPTED : selector also applying here </p>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a unique identifier such as a `class` or an `id` to specifically make the first select tag `readonly` and not both.. for example, here, am using tag and an attribute selector to select the tags which have `readonly` attribute

```css
select[readonly]:-moz-read-only {
  /* For Firefox */
  pointer-events: none;
}

select[readonly]:read-only {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p> ACCEPTED </p>
<select readonly>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<br>
<p> UNACCEPTED : selector also applying here </p>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

The selector you are using is a tag selector and will select any `select` tag and turn it into readonly.

---

Adding some details based on the comments,

You can disable the tab focus by using `tabindex` attribute with a value set to `false` on the `select` tag

Also, you should not rely on the data passed from the client side if it's meant to be readonly. You need to have a proper validation in place in the backend which will prevent a user from passing any false or malicious data. No matter what you use, simple HTML CSS solution like above or disabling keys using JavaScript, you cannot prevent the user to not to alter the value of the tag.

Comment: This is not a good idea actually. User can still focus on said element through tab-in and change the selected option.

Comment: @Nisarg thank you. I didn't know that was a requirement by the OP, have added a solution for the same.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-read-only), `<select>` element is considered `read-only` as it is not explicitly editable by the user.

> The **:read-write** pseudo-class must match any element falling into one of the following categories, which for the purposes of Selectors are thus considered user-alterable: [SELECTORS]
>
> - **input** elements to which the readonly attribute applies, and that are mutable (i.e. that do not have the readonly attribute specified and that are not disabled)
> - **textarea** elements that do not have a readonly attribute, and that are not disabled
> - **elements** that are editing hosts or editable and are neither input elements nor textarea elements
>
> The **:read-only** pseudo-class must match all other HTML elements.

You should instead use `disabled` attribute to indicate that the user cannot interact with the `<select>` element. With `disabled` attribute, you don't have to specify extra CSS to disable mouse interaction with the element.

Here's how it would work:

```html
<p> ACCEPTED </p>
<select disabled>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<br>
<p> UNACCEPTED : selector also applying here </p>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry i cannot use disabled as i mentioned in my question, select tag should be readable in post request that's why i just need to set it as read only.

Comment: @ViperTecPro Then you could use some [Javascript, as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5426387/5894241) to prevent the user from changing values. But it is not a good idea to just disable mouse interaction, because the user could simply focus on the select element through tabbing and then change values by pressing up-down keys.

Comment: Great very good point about tab, is there any we can disable tab interaction using css, i think not i've to use `ev.preventDefault();` to prevent that from happening, is that correct ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro I don't think there is anything other than "disabled" attribute. Your best bet would be to use some Javascript here. Apart from `e.preventDefault()` I've seen people use `element.blur()` on the `focus` event.